# Sending national symbols from Android to C# Windows through Socket

Tags: c#, android, sockets

There is an XML file, containing some national symbols data. It is the SMS messages and their bodies.
I use Socket connection to transfer that xml file to Windows PC, where C# code receives it.
How to pack and send the data in such case..?

```
DataOutputStream outToClient = outToClient = new DataOutputStream (inSock.getOutputStream ( ));
outToClient.writeBytes(Data2Send); //<------Data2Send - string with xml data containing unicode
```

In C# there is no UTF16, only UTF32 and UTF8.. and on Android there is no UTF32, and I suppose the national symbols in Android are coded in UTF16, so therefor it is the collision. So, when I do:

```
string xmlData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
```

Then data from UTF8 range of symbols are decoded right, but the national symbols are left as binary data, though before sending, on Android side - I can read them Ok.

Somebody told me about Base64 class.. but before I start to try it, i want to ask if any other way to do that?

Comment: You can convert the encoding of characters in any of these languages.  Just  send it in a single format (UTF-8 is the most standard) and read the data in as UTF-8 and you'll be fine.

Comment: Hi, all data by default on Android coded as UTF8.. so, sending that buffer I should get them correct using Encoding.UTF8.GetString... But it is not. As I said national symbols wrong, pls, see the <body> tag in  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes' ?><messages number="1099"><message date_sent="1502638182000" date_received="1502638177957" id="1694"><subject></subject><body>>ABC? 2 =B5@=5B ?> 4>3>2>@C 75428 70:0=G8205BAO 15.08.2017. 5>1E>48<> >?;0B8BL ?5@8>4.</body></message>

Comment: on Android it's ok.. the string is correct, but after "send-receive" transaction becomes wrong